# Casting String to Int and Vice Versa NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, casting

I would like to make a program where the user inputs and that will be converted into numbers, and the numbers can also get changed into the input again. But I don't know how to do that, but I really want to because my school monitors my email and I want to have a secret password sharing with my friends. For Example making a=1 and b=2 so it will print something like 1 2 1 2 1 2 which means a b a b a b. Thank you.

Comment: +1 because it is a funny thing to do to prevent monitoring; a better thing to do is using real encryption.

Comment: Simple encryption can be achieved with tools like 7zip http://www.medicalnerds.com/how-to-encrypt-zip-files-securely-using-7zip/

Answer (score 2):

You are talking abount casting an string to integer, but thats noch what you want to do. You want to map a number to a string. Use a Hashmap for doing this.

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("a",1);
    map.put("b",2);
    String input = "a b a b a b";
    for(String s : input.split(" "))
        System.out.print(map.get(s) + " ");
```

Output:

```
    1 2 1 2 1 2
```